# Mixing Windows and Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I'm currently trying to set up a website that uses both windows authentication and forms authentication.  I am using ASP.NET MVC and both IIS6 and 7 need to be supported.  How would I go about letting known AD users into the app (their AD id is stored against their user record in the application database) and directing everyone else to a standard username/password page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the answer is no.  We've had to set up 2 sites, the main application with forms authentication and a separate windows authenticated site which redirects to the forms site with a token which expires quickly telling the forms site that an authenticated user is incomming.

Answer (score 1):

What about the option using custom 401 redirect at IIS level outlined in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx#mixedsecurity_topic4)